# Calculating without determinant the volume of a parallelepiped in the vector space $\mathbb{R}^{3}$ over $\mathbb{R}$?

Tags: linear-algebra, recreational-mathematics

Let $a_{1}, a_{2}, a_{3} \in \mathbb{R}^{3}(\mathbb{R})$ form a linearly independent set. It is well-known that the parallelepiped $P$ having $a_{1}, a_{2}, a_{3}$ as adjacent sides has volume equal to the determinant of the matrix whose rows are $a_{1}, a_{2}, a_{3}$.

But I wonder if there is any labor-saving way to calculate $P$ without using determinant in general? I say "in general" because if $a_{1}, a_{2}, a_{3}$ happen to be vertical to each other then the volume of $P$ equals simply $|| a_{1} ||\cdot ||a_{2}||\cdot ||a_{3}||.$

Comment: How about the vector triple product: $\vec{a}\cdot(\vec{b}\times\vec{c})$? This isn't philosophically any different since cross products are closely related to determinants anyway..

Comment: Yes, thanks. I kind of implicitly ruled it out because of its kinship to determinant.

Comment: I don't really think there's anything else you can do, honestly, unless you want to work with the explicit expression for the vector triple product. That *is* the volume formula, so you're going to end up doing that computation regardless.

Comment: I would like to know something similar to Pick's theorem, which gives a nice formula for the area of any lattice triangle seemingly unrelated to the usual triangle area formula.